# UINavigation Controller is not working with present modelviewcontrolller

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, navigationcontroller

I'm using navigation controller:

1. So, from my first view to I go second view through push view controller
2. And form second view to I go third view through present model view controller
3. Now my problem is that, on third view I want to go fourth view through push view controller but nothing happen when I try to push for fourth view, what I do now?

I'm using this code

in my delegate.h file i make a property of navigation controller:

```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationControler;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *loginViewController;
```

and in my delegate.m file:

```
    self.loginViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationControler = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.loginViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationControler;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and when i go third view through presetmodelviewcontroller like this:

```
Redeem *redeem = [[Redeem alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:redeem animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and after reached to second view i want to go third view with push view like this

```
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){
     MyPurchaseCards *mypurchase = [[MyPurchaseCards alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:mypurchase animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

but nothing happen and also when i try to get all previous controller like this

```
   NSArray *arr = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
   NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```

but array show me null value. WHY?????

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you use a `presentViewController` presenting the *third* controller, your main controller is now the *third* and it is the controller on the top of the screen (it is called `presentedViewController`).

If you push the *fourth* controller on the navigation stack, **it is pushed** but you can't see it since it is under the *third*, because the *third* is your top controller and it is the controller on the top of the screen.

In order to load the fourth controller you have to:

- dismiss the *third* and in the completion block...
- ...push the *fourth*

Comment: yes i do as it but this is go back to second view not fourth view check this. [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void)
     {
        MyPurchaseCards *mypurchase = [[MyPurchaseCards alloc] init];
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:mypurchase animated:YES];
     }]; @Marco Pace

Comment: Very strange, I use the same code in my current project and it works. Can you post the navigation controllers array before the dismissViewControllerAnimated and after the pushViewController?

Comment: you mean first i get array of navigation before dismiss.. and send you??? @Macro Pace

Comment: Ok, when i get all navigationcontroller and save in NSArray but array showing null value nothing is anything in my array                                                              NSArray *allViews = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
    NSLog(@"%@",allViews);  @Marco PAce

Comment: Mmm there is something strange. Can you post some code of your implementation please? 
Perhaps it is a simple fix reading the code.

Comment: in my delegate.h property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationControler;
property (strong, nonatomic) HomeViewController *homeViewController; and in my delegate.m self.loginViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.navigationControler = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.loginViewController]; and after presenmodelview controller my all viewcontrollers in null @Marco Pace

Comment: Can you modify the first post? It very hard to read it on a comment... Please insert also the methodwhere you present 4th controller and qhen you dismiss it - more code is better :)

Comment: I've 2 questions. FIRST: the Redeem *redeem, where is presented? Is that code user in your navigation controller, first, second, third or fourth view controller? SECOND: where is dismissViewControllerAnimated used?  Is that code user in your navigation controller, first, second, third or fourth view controller?

Comment: @AliRaza unfortunately I can't since it is a code of my work.

Comment: when i am on third view there i use dismiss. and Redeem is presented in dismiss block

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your third view controller is not wrapped in a navigation controller. Instead of pushing straightly the third view controller, you might want to create a navigation controller with the third view controller as a root view controller. Then you'll be able to push your 4th view controller with the code you mentioned.